# Edit selected custom object properties at run time

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a requirement in which i should read all the property of the class and display them in UI and the user should be able to edit them and again save the edited property values to the same object. The custom object may have one or more  custom type with in it. So i need to allow the user to edit those object properties referred in the parent object too. Suggest an approach to do the above requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same control that Visual Studio uses for it's UI editor: the [ProperyGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.110).aspx).

It does exactly what you want, see [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx)